# Как сначала выполнить js скрипт в расширении для хрома, а потом вывести определённый попап?

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

я написал самовызывающуюся функцию в background.js, которая выполняет всё что мне надо (подписывается на событитя и тп).
как только я добавляю в manifest.json

```
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "64.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
```

в этом случае background.js не выполняется, выполняется лишь только вывод popup.html без всяких

Как сначала выполнить js скрипт в расширении для хрома, а потом вывести определённый(в зависимости от условий в background.js) popup.html?

Comment: а вы отправляете сообщение их основного ( не контентного) js файла?

Comment: "background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": [ "data/jquery.min.js", "background.js" ]
  },

Comment: Я имею в виду внутри самого скрипта вы посылаете сообщение? через chrome.tabs.sendMessage или chrome.runtime.sendMessage

Comment: я ничего такого не посылаю, только так     chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
        makeMagic();
    });

Answer (score 0):

Судя по вашим комментариям, у вас просто не происходит вызов в контентный скрипт.

В своем контент скрипте вы подписываетесь на события, но из основоного js скрипты вы ничего не посылаете.

Внутри

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    makeMagic();
})
```

Вам необходимо отправлять сообщения, чтобы вы могли их обрабатывать. Делается это с помощью [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage) или [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage).

Подробнее можно посмоотреть тут: [Message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).